# CSS in Public dont work in Show Controller

Tags: php, css, laravel

show function can't get the files in public

I tried in other controller without resources it can read the css at img in public sorry for my english

```
public function show($id)
{
    $brand = Brand::where('c_id', $id)->get();
    return view('brand.pick')->with('brand',$brand);
}
```

This is my HTML blade file

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
      @foreach($brand as $b)
                        <option value="{{$b->b_name}}" selected>{{$b->b_name}} 
   </option>    

   @endforeach
```

[image]

the page don't have css and image

This is in Index function the css is working when I run in show function 
[image]

This is my Blade file Layout.app

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>{{config ('app.name')}}</title>
<link rel="icon" href="img/favicon.png">
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- animate CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<!-- owl carousel CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<!-- themify CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themify-icons.css">
<!-- flaticon CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flaticon.css">
<!-- font awesome CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
<!-- swiper CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper.min.css">
<!-- style CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
@include('inc.nav');
@yield('content');


<br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
<!-- footer part start-->
<section class="footer-area section_padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xl-2 col-sm-4 mb-4 mb-xl-0 single-footer- 
  widget">
                <h4>Top Products</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Managed Website</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manage Reputation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Power Tools</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Marketing Service</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
      <div class="col-xl-2 col-sm-4 mb-4 mb-xl-0 single-footer-widget">
                     <h4>Quick Links</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Brand Assets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Investor Relations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-sm-4 mb-4 mb-xl-0 single-footer- 
    widget">
                <h4>Features</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Brand Assets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Investor Relations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-2 col-sm-4 mb-4 mb-xl-0 single-footer- 
  widget">
                <h4>Resources</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Guides</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Experts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Agencies</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xl-4 col-sm-8 col-md-8 mb-4 mb-xl-0 single- 
   footer-widget">
                <h4>Newsletter</h4>
                <p>You can trust us. we only send promo offers,</p>
                <div class="form-wrap" id="mc_embed_signup">
                    <form target="_blank" 
action="https://spondonit.us12.list-manage.com/subscribe/post? 
 u=1462626880ade1ac87bd9c93a&amp;id=92a4423d01" method="get" class="form- 
inline">
                        <input class="form-control" name="EMAIL" 
placeholder="Your Email Address" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
onblur="this.placeholder = 'Your Email Address '" required="" 
type="email">
                        <button class="click-btn btn btn-default text- 
uppercase">subscribe</button>
                        <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;">
                            <input 
name="b_36c4fd991d266f23781ded980_aefe40901a" tabindex="-1" value="" 
type="text">
                        </div>

                        <div class="info"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<footer class="copyright_part bottom">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center ">
            <p class="footer-text m-0 col-lg-8 col-md-12"><!-- Link back 
to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
Copyright &copy;<script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script> 
All 
rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="ti-heart" aria- 
  hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" 
target="_blank">Colorlib</a>
<!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC 
BY 
3.0. --></p>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12  text-center text-lg-right 
footer-social">
                <a href="#"><i class="ti-facebook"></i></a>
                <a href="#"> <i class="ti-twitter"></i> </a>
                <a href="#"><i class="ti-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="ti-skype"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<!-- footer part end-->

<!-- jquery plugins here-->
<!-- jquery -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- popper js -->
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap js -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- aos js -->
<script src="js/aos.js"></script>
<!-- easing js -->
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
<!-- swiper js -->
<script src="js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<!-- swiper js -->
<script src="js/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<!-- particles js -->
<script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!-- carousel js -->
<script src="js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<!-- swiper js -->
<script src="js/swiper_custom.js"></script>
<!-- custom js -->
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: can you give your html(blade) file also

Comment: `$brand = Brand::where('c_id', $id)->get();` try to change this code to `$brand = Brand::where('c_id', $id)->first();`

Comment: I update my question I put some print screen

Comment: If the structure in your Blade file is the same as it is in the first one it should work. Can you maybe show your *layouts.app* and your Blade from the first screenshot?

Comment: the CSS is working when I don't use the show function its just when I use show function it dont read the CSS btw my CSS and IMAGE is in the PUBLIC FOLDER

Comment: Show us your blade files: layouts and view.

Comment: I update my post

Answer (score 0):

Use asset helper of laravel.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
```

By default asset helper will search path inside public folder, or you can configure asset url in .env file.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-asset

Comment: How? I use custom css and bootstrap in public folder

Comment: Place all .css in css folder and all images in img or image folder inside public folder. Then you can use asset helper function.